# Java SOAP Service & JBOSS

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jboss

> setup VM argument for java soap web service ????

```
I have a SOAP web service I want to deploy to JBOSS,
```

> But I do need to setup VM argument for my web service.
>   my VM argument look like 
>  -Dabc.config=file:///folderA/abc.xml

```
How ????
```

Comment: Modify `standalone.sh` or (on Windows) `standalone.bat` and restart JBoss.

Comment: Thanks... Elliott....it work fine now

Answer (score 0):

Thanks alot Elliott for answering my Q....
"Modify standalone.sh or (on Windows) standalone.bat and restart JBoss. –  Elliott Frisch 12